# Using fingerprints everywhere to identify at physical, ID required, places

Tags: identity, fingerprint, identity-management

I was wondering why people can't just use fingerprints to retrieve all necessary documents where required.

What would be the problem with such form of authentication, which could be used via fingerprint readers with screens, at all point where ID was required?

Answer (score 1):

The question is pretty broad - talking about "people", "documents" and "all point where ID was required" without being more specific about the use cases.

One obvious obstacle to using the fingerprint is that it first would need to be recorded and associated with the person. Then this association would need to be made available wherever the identity needs to be checked. If it should be a replacement of the ID, then it cannot be just be embedded in the (physical or digital) ID, but has to be available in some huge database for online or offline access. This kind of data collection and data access is often seen as too much of a privacy invasion, at least in countries where the people have a say in decisions about such things.

Apart from that a fingerprint might not be reliable enough, i.e. the process has errors which depend on the technology (false positives and false negatives, ability to spoof) but might also be intensified with specific environmental conditions (moist, dirt, ...). And, fingers might actually be damaged (or even lost) in which case the method will no longer work. In other words: there needs to be an alternative way in case the fingerprint will not work and thus it cannot be a full replacement of the ID.

Fingerprints also provide limited security, depending on the balance chosen between false positives, false negatives, not working at all and the ability to spoof. Thus it might not be secure enough for all use cases, since different kinds of "documents" might require a different level of assurance of the identity of the user.